# Remove Save Anyway Libre Office OneDrive

Tags: libreoffice

When I try to save a working document from OneDrive with an Libre program I receive this popup. Sometimes the document will not save if the popup does not appear. Is there any way to skip this screen? Of course if I'm hitting save, I want it to be saved. This only happens when working on a document from a sharedrive, for which I am the only user.

[image]